# Elastic search query based on score in the response

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, elasticsearch, lucene, querydsl

Can we query the ES to return only one result which is having highest score in the response, when there are multiple records matching the query?.

Let me know, if there is any sample query. thanks.

Sample response/document:- I use like search. 
As of now my service returns below records.

```
record1 - product1, value1, score=1.5 
record2 - product1, value2, score=1.4
record3 - product2, value1, score=1.7
record4 - product2, value2, score=0.8
record5 - product3, value1, score=1.2
```

I want the result with only below records, which will filter product, based on the score. Only one record per product.

```
record1 - product1, value1, score=1.5
record3 - product2, value1, score=1.7
record5 - product3, value1, score=1.2
```

Further details:-
Created an custom Analyser:-

```
"analysis": {

    "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
            "type": "edge_ngram",
            "min_gram": "1",
            "max_gram": "20"
        }
    },
    "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
            "filter": [
                "autocomplete_filter"
            ],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }
    }

}
```

Mapping:-

```
"PRODUCT_ID": {

    "analyzer": "autocomplete",
    "type": "string"

}
```

Query:-

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "PRODUCT_ID": "CON-HSH-AS"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [],
  "aggs": {}
}
```

Comment: please add some code what u have tried ???

Comment: It is possible. Use `"size":1` and, **by default**, it will give you only one document which should have the highest score. Documents are sorted by default on score so, if you haven't changed the sorting mechanism, `"size": 1` is enough.

Comment: size:1.. will return only document at any case.Bt my usecase is different..

Comment: You need to provide more details: the mapping of the index, sample documents and the full query you are using now.

Comment: updated the details..

Comment: If you don't mind, I asked for the mapping of the index, not the mapping of a single field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out [top-hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation). Maybe it'll be of help for your use case :)